# Setting up a Pardot Sandbox

Tags: sandbox, pardot

So we recently purchased a license for a Pardot sandbox (We've got Plus edition so we don't have one by default) and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to set it up. I'm following the instructions in this article: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.pardot_sf_connector_sandbox.htm&type=5

But after going to Pardot Account Setup I don't see the option to create a new Business Unit:
[image]

I'm unexperienced with Pardot so I'm sure I must be missing some basic stuff and any help would be much appreaciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was a license match on the sandbox: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000335272&type=1