How to create business unit in SF Account Engagement
I recently installed the Account Engagement (formerly Pardot) app in production and refreshed the sandbox from production. While I can see the option to create business unit in production, it’s not visible in the sandbox. Could someone guide me on what I might be missing


Possibly a dupe of https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/378798/setting-up-a-pardot-sandbox

You only get Sandboxes with Advanced & Premium editions of Account Engagement. You can pay extra for it in Plus I think, talk to your AE.
